# Running Python in a command prompt

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I have some python code that I want to run from the cmd prompt, but it's not working, my partner told me if I had this statement in my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    xs, a0, a1, y0, y1, ys = encode(sys.argv[1])
    np.set_printoptions(precision=6, suppress=True)
```

then it should be able to be run. I'll post my entire code and my command prompt errors to see if you guys can help

[image]

```
import random
import numpy as np
import sys
import pprint
from numpy import linalg as LA

#Takes in a n value
def encode(n):

    xA0 = np.zeros((n+3,1))
    xA1 = np.zeros((n+3,1))
    xStream = np.zeros((n+3,1))
#Creates a random x
    for i in range(0, n):
        xStream[i,0] = random.randint(0,1)

#Creates A0 and A1 based on size
    xA0[0,0] = 1
    xA0[2,0] = 1
    xA0[3,0] = 1

    xA1[0,0] = 1
    xA1[1,0] = 1
    xA1[3,0] = 1

    A0 = np.zeros((n+3,n+3))
    A1 = np.zeros((n+3,n+3))
    y0 = np.zeros((n+3,1))
    y1 = np.zeros((n+3,1))
    yStream = []

#Creates A0 and A1 using method defined in description
    for i in range(0,n+3):
        for k in range (0,i+1):
            A0[i,k] = xA0[i-k,0]
            A1[i,k] = xA1[i-k,0]

#A0*x and A1*x to get y0 and y1
    for i in range(0,n+3):
        y0[i,0] = np.dot(A0[i,:], xStream)
        y1[i,0] = np.dot(A1[i,:], xStream)

#answers mod 2 to get real answers
    for i in range(0,n+3):
        y0[i,0] = y0[i,0]%2
        y1[i,0] = y1[i,0]%2

#combined for yStream
    for i in range(0,n+3):
        yStream.append([y0[i,0],y1[i,0]])

    print("x:")
    print(xStream)
    print("\n")
    print("A0:")
    print(A0)
    print("\n")
    print("A1:")
    print(A1)
    print("\n")
    print("y0:")
    print(y0)
    print("\n")
    print("y1:")
    print(y1)
    print("\n")
    print("yStream:")
    print(yStream)

    return xStream, A0, A1, y0, y1, yStream

# This is only or when encode is used as a stand-alone module
# Read command line argument. Must be exactly one argument.
# It outputs on the console
if __name__ == '__main__':
    xs, a0, a1, y0, y1, ys = encode(sys.argv[1])
    np.set_printoptions(precision=6, suppress=True)

    print("x:")
    print(xs)
    print("\n")
    print("A0:")
    print(a0)
    print("\n")
    print("A1:")
    print(a1)
    print("\n")
    print("y0:")
    print(y0)
    print("\n")
    print("y1:")
    print(y1)
    print("\n")
    print("yStream:")
    print(ys)
```

Comment: How did you install python and did you allow it to add itself to your system path?

Comment: Try using `py` instead of `python` in the command prompt.

Comment: @Andy I think I just used an installer, and idk is there anyway I could check?

Comment: @Andy If he installed Python

Comment: Normally, the installer just installs to C:/Python

Comment: @SireRNavith didnt work

Comment: You have to set ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE

Comment: @jakekimds my python folder is at D:/Python

Comment: @srekcahrai what does that mean?

Comment: The installer's default install directory is `C:\Python27` or `C:\Python34`. If you are sure that Python is installed in that directory, then try running the command `D:\Python\Python.exe filename` replacing filename with the name of your file.

Comment: @jakekimds yeah I know but i changed it because my C drive is my SSD

Comment: @jakekimds i did that and now im getting this:

D:\Python>Python.exe Encode.py
Python.exe: can't open file 'Encode.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @Josephhooper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7 see the best answer

Comment: Try repeating the last command but with the entire file path of the file instead of just the file name. Plus, verify the file name is Encode.py

Comment: @jakekimds I can get into the python interpreter but it keeps saying that Encode isn't defined. But it definitely is, I feel like it has something to do with the path. I put the entire file path and it still didnt work

Comment: cd to the directory holding your python script.  Type: `D:\Python\Python Encode.py`

Comment: When running it with the whole file path, remember to quote the file path to escape the spaces.

Comment: @jakekimds it should run just like if I wanted to run a java file right? It probably has something to do with my file id k what hough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have installed into D:\Python, copy the following into an editor and save it as a bat file (say `runpython.bat`) then run it (EDITED with thanks to @eryksun)  Assumes Python 2:

```
@SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\Python;D:\Python\Scripts

@ASSOC .py=Python.File
@ASSOC .pyc=Python.CompiledFile
@ASSOC .pyo=Python.CompiledFile
@ASSOC .pyw=Python.NoConFile

@FTYPE Python.CompiledFile="D:\Python\python.exe" "%%1" %%*
@FTYPE Python.File="D:\Python\python.exe" "%%1" %%*
@FTYPE Python.NoConFile="D:\Python\pythonw.exe" "%%1" %%*
@SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.py
```

You should now be able to run python programs from the command-line

Comment: I run it as an administrator and it immediately closes out so I cant see what it says, but it didnt seem to work

Comment: @eryksun: fair enough, no argument with any of your points, I'll amend.

Comment: @eryksun:  no `@echo off`.  I find that when adding a new line to the type of file I omit the @ so I can see it is being executed.  When I'm happy I prefix the @.  Maybe its just me, but you have to let me retain *some* of my original :-)

Answer (score 1):

Goto

`My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables >`

Add Path of your Python in `Variable value`.

[image]

Comment: Would I just add D:\Python to varibale value? Because that's where my Python.exe is located

Comment: Yes, be sure you put `;`.

Comment: I did it but for some reason it's still not working for me. I assume it's just like getting java to work though. not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: To make sure it worked, type `python` in command prompt or run. If it gives you python shell, it worked.